# Address of an empty base optimized subobject

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, void-pointers, is-empty, void-safety

Let's say that I have a value:

```
int i = 0;
```

And an empty class eligible for being empty-base optimized:

```
struct Empty{
  // stuff that passes
  // static_assert( std::is_empty<Empty>::value );
 };
```

Is it legal to:

```
Empty& e = *reinterpret_cast<Empty*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&i)); //?
// do stuff with e
```

Comment: `Empty*` is not allowed to alias an `int`eger, so I'd say no.

Comment: @Swordfish `int` is accidental to the question. What type can it be so that `Empty*` can alias it?

Comment: If you don't want this to simply be closed as duplicate of the post explaining strict aliasing, why not go over what you are trying to accomplish? This has the feeling of an XY problem.

Comment: @tsuki please, read for yourself: [basic.lval/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)

Comment: What stuff can you do with `e`, given that it is empty?

Comment: @MSalters Call its copy constructor, move constructor and its destructor. It's a part of a metaprogramming library that deals with memory management.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [online C++ standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf), a cast from one pointer type to a different pointer type and then back is conditionally valid:

> 5.2.10 Reinterpret cast
>
> (7) Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer
>   to T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment
>   requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its
>   original type yields the original pointer value.

This means, that the cast per se from `int*` to `Empty*` is valid as long as `Empty` does not have stricter alignment requirements than `int`, and you can later cast back to `int*`.

Note, however, that this does not mean that you may access/dereference the `Empty*`-object (as it isn't an `Empty`-object to which the pointer points).

So the pure cast is OK, but dereferencing it then yields UB.